# Creating Multiple Lines with Line Chart

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am making use of code example and advice to add two or more lines in my line chart. I have difficulty doing so, as `chtChart.data` adds the chart data to the chart and causes an update. How should additional lines be added? In my code below, `chtChart.data = data1` is replaced by `data2`.

```
let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "CH4")
let line2 = LineChartDataSet(values: avgValue, label: "Warnings")
line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
line2.colors = [NSUIColor.gray]
let data1 = LineChartData()
let data2 = LineChartData()
data1.addDataSet(line1)
data2.addDataSet(line2)
chtChart.data = data1
chtChart.data = data2
```

Comment: Get rid of `data2` and call `data1.addDataSet(...)` with both `line1` and `line2`

Comment: Is it possible to write a code example of this?

Comment: Also, what happens to chtChart.data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show multiple lines on one chart you need one instance of `LineChartData` with multiple data sets added to it.

Replace your code with:

```
let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "CH4")
let line2 = LineChartDataSet(values: avgValue, label: "Warnings")
line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
line2.colors = [NSUIColor.gray]
let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [line1, line2])
chtChart.data = data
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem solved!

Also got it sorted via: 
data1.addDataSet(line1)
data1.addDataSet(line2)
chtChart.data = data1